# Object Required error 424 when calling subroutine

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

[image]

I am trying to call a subroutine that will extend formulas to the last row when anything on Column B of the excel worksheet TitlesList changes.  The formulas can not exist before anything is added, thus should only exist in a row after a change is made in column B.  The purpose is to allow an API from FLOW insert a line in excel, then excel will apply a formula to create a new value in another column and FLOW will then update the new value in Planner.  (complex ?)  Specifically, I am trying to ensure that a card title in planner always has a unique value in front of the title.  For example if the card title is:  "This is a card title"  I have a flow that will successfully add a row into excel, but it will add the row in the last empty row of the worksheet.  At that point I want to extend the formula, that adds a sequence number, for example No. 23, in to a column, then concatenate the sequence number and create a new column title as such: "23 - This is a card title"  then FLOW will run a routine to update from Excel to Planner, and thus keeping all the cards and tasks with a number.  (to think this would be easier if the Planner folks would allow custom fields).  What am I doing wrong in this VBA.  Sorry not much experience with VBA.

The code to call the sub is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Targe As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B500")) Is Nothing Then
    'If any changes occurr in column B
          Call ExtendRows
          ' Then extend the formulas
    End If
End Sub
```

The code to extend formulas is:

```
Sub ExtendRows()
    lr = Cells.Find("ROW", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
    'find the last row with a formula
    Range("A2").AutoFill Range("A2:A" & (lr + 1))
    'fill the formula in the last row
End Sub
```

The error is: Run-Time error '424' Object Required and it returns me back to the Worksheet_Change code.
What am I doing wrong?  I have read all about this error, but I can't seem to figure out what I to do.  Do I need to declare something, somewhere?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If `Find()` doesn't get a match then it returns `Nothing` - you can't get the `Row` property of `Nothing`.

Better like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Targe As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B500")) Is Nothing Then
        ExtendRows Me '<< pass the worksheet to check
    End If
End Sub


'gets the worksheet to look at...
Sub ExtendRows(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("ROW", ws.Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, _
                           xlByRows, xlPrevious, False)
    if not f is nothing then
        ws.Range("A2").AutoFill ws.Range("A2:A" & f.row+1)
    else
        'did not find "ROW"
    end if
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try!